In GitHub Actions, block merge if a specific label exists
I want to prevent branches that are 1 week stale from being merged. I set up actions/stale to mark stale PRs with the Stale label. Now I need to prevent this PR from being merged.
I could always just add another workflow that checks for the label and blocks the PR, but I was wondering if there's a simpler way that can achieve that.
